# Swift JSON decoding with dependent types

Tags: json, swift, decodable

I'm trying to decode "dependent" JSON API responses in Swift. Let's imagine a fictional API with two endpoints:

- `/players`, returns an array of objects with following attributes:

  - `id`, an integer representing the player ID
  - `name`, a string representing the player name
- `/games`, returns an array of objects with following attributes:

  - `name`, a string representing the name of the game
  - `playerId1`, an integer representing the ID of the first player
  - `playerId2`, an integer representing the ID of the second player

I model each type with a Swift `struct`:

```swift
struct Player: Decodable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String?
}

struct Game: Decodable {
    var name: String
    var player1: Player
    var player2: Player
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case player1 = "playerId1"
        case player2 = "playerId2"
    }
}
```

I want to decode the response from `/games` into an array of `Game` objects, with correct `Player`s attributes, so I extended `Game` with a custom initializer but I don't know how to retrieve all player attributes:

```swift
extension Game {
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        
        //                                             HOW SHOULD I RETRIEVE THE PLAYER'S NAME GIVEN THEIR ID HERE?
        //                                                                         |
        //                                                                         |
        //                                                                         V
        player1 = Player(id: try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .player1), name: nil)
        player2 = Player(id: try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .player2), name: nil)
    }
}
```

---

To summarize, the API response from `/games` does not contain all the information I need for full initialization, so how should I proceed:

- can/should I make two API calls, one to `/games` and another one to `players` and somehow merge them before decoding?
- should I initialize my `Player`s only partly (leaving unknown stuff to `nil`) and fill the details later? (That sound dangerous and cumbersome.)
- anything else?

**If you want to experiment with it, you can find a full example [here](https://pastebin.com/2rT3c26P)**

Comment: Graphql might help here https://graphql.org

Comment: @Cristik Thanks for the suggestion, but I would rather avoid GraphQL as I don't have control over the API and would like to avoid running my own server mimicking the original API in GraphQL :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to add two lazy instantiated properties to get the `Player` instances from the array.

The benefit of a lazy property over a computed property is that the value is calculated once and not until it's being accessed the first time. And a custom `init(from:)` method is not needed.

```
struct Game: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let playerId1: Int
    let playerId2: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case name, playerId1, playerId2 }

    lazy var player1 : Player? = players.first{ $0.id == playerId1 }
    lazy var player2 : Player? = players.first{ $0.id == playerId2 }
   
}
```

---

Alternatively create a `CodingUserInfoKey`

```
extension CodingUserInfoKey {
    static let players = CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue: "players")!
}
```

and an extension of `JSONDecoder`

```
extension JSONDecoder {
    convenience init(players: [Player]) {
        self.init()
        self.userInfo[.players] = players
    }
}
```

and pass the `players` array in the `userInfo` object of the JSON decoder

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder(players: players)
let games = try! decoder.decode([Game].self, from: Data(gamesResponse.utf8))
dump(games[0].player1)
```

Now you can get the actual players in the `init(from:` method.

```
struct Game: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let player1: Player
    let player2: Player
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name, playerId1, playerId2
    }
}

extension Game {
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        guard let players = decoder.userInfo[.players] as? [Player] else { fatalError("No players array available") }
        name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        let playerId1 = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .playerId1)
        let playerId2 = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .playerId2)
        player1 = players.first{ $0.id == playerId1 }!
        player2 = players.first{ $0.id == playerId2 }!
    }
}
```

The code assumes that the `players` array contains all `Player` instances corresponding to the `playerId` values. If not then you have to declare `player1` and `player2` as optional and remove the exclamation marks.

Comment: `players` being some shared mutable global variable?

Comment: @vadian Thanks for the nice answer. How could I make that work without the global variable, _i.e._ `players` and `games` would be instantiated by my ViewModel, so how do I define the models without the global variable? (Sorry that this was not captured by my example)

Comment: @vadian Thanks a lot for the update, that's exactly what I wanted and I would never have come up with such a construct myself! One final question: why did you decide to do an extension of `JSONDecoder` rather than a sub-class? Is it not considered "bad practice" to add very specific `init` to a generic class like `JSONDecoder`?

Comment: No, it's not bad practice. I'm *extending* the functionality of `JSONDecoder` by adding a convenience initializer.